# How to Show Lightning Modal pop up in custom list view button

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning

[image: I need a custom in that red rectangle]

I need to display a lightning modal pop up in list view of custom object, we tried by creating the List button in the object and VF page which calls Lightning modal pop up but the problem over here was, when we click the button it redirects to another page. we need to display lightning pop up using custom list view button inside the same page like standard button. Like this below

[image]

Please provide some suggestions.

Comment: Following this question...Have you got your answer?